# When is the Sharing Button visible for a Record?

Tags: sharing, button, owd

When can I view Sharing Button on a Record in general?

- Is it only when an Object is set to Private on Org Wide Defaults?

Or

- When the Objects OWD is Private or Public Read only?

Is there any other scenario this "Sharing Button" can be visible for a Record.

Comment: If anyone's looking for this in the Lightning UI, look no more.  There **is still *NO* Sharing button in the Lightning UI**.  See this [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000339349&type=1&mode=1) and this [IdeaExchange idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000LmluQAC).

Confirmed as of the Winter '20 release.  Crazy that this still hasn't been prioritized...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a small article on [Salesforce help](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_general_why_cant_i_see_the_sharing.htm)

> You have access to the Sharing button when your sharing model is either Private or Public Read Only for a type of record or related record. For example, the Sharing button may appear on an account even though your organization-wide default for accounts is Public Read/Write, if your organization-wide default for related opportunities is Public Read Only.
>
> When the button is available on the page layout, administrators see
> the button on all records. Non-administrators see this button on
> records that only they own.

Here you have an example of other scenario and an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The OWD of Activity is **Private**. but there is **no** **Sharing** button is Task level. So the above explanation is not applicable for Activity. We can't even write sharing rules to share an activity.

Comment: @OlesMalkov. can you verify this pls.

Comment: Well, that is an exception in SF sharing model. We can't share activities, however if sharing model is "controlled by parent", we can share parent object.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing you must check to view Sharing Button. If **Edit** permission on Object not checked Owner will not share record to anyone. **User profile** should have **Edit access** on Object